# Setting state only working after rerender

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I have this Firebase Firestore query set up in my `useEffect` hook:

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);

  const getUserFavorites = async () => {
    const favoritesRef = collection(db, "favorites");
    const q = query(favoritesRef, where("userId", "==", user.uid));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const fetchedFavorites = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (document) => {
      const docRef = doc(db, "receipes", document.data().recipeId);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      const data = docSnap.data();
      fetchedFavorites.push(data);
    });
    setFavorites(fetchedFavorites);
    console.log("favorites " + favorites);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserFavorites();
  }, []);
```

Upon first render of the page the `favorites` will be `[]` and after a re-render it will be populated. When logging within the `forEach` I can see that the query is working, so I suspect the async `forEach` being the culprit here. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should not use `async` function with a `forEach()` loop. You can use a `for-of` loop with the same code or use `Promise.all()` as shown below:

```
const getUserFavorites = async () => {
  const favoritesRef = collection(db, "favorites");
  const q = query(favoritesRef, where("userId", "==", user.uid));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  const favPromises = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => getDoc(doc(db, "receipes", d.data().recipeId)))
  const fetchedFavs = (await Promise.all(favPromises)).map((fav) => fav.data());

  setFavorites(fetchedFavs);
  console.log("favorites " + fetchedFavs);
};
```

Also checkout: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) for more information.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the info linked, clears it up for me.